# Форматирование вывода в консоли IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ascii

Делал шахматы в IntelliJ Idea под MacOS, потом перенес на Windows и в итоге форматирование сместилось из-за того, что фигуры шире, чем символы-границы (на маке было все ровно). Выравниваний не было, просто загонял пробелами пустоту от левой стены до фигуры и потом от фигуры до правой. Что-то вообще тут можно сделать? Заранее спасибо.

[image: Вот так это выглядит сейчас]

Comment: О, ascii-графика. Добавьте, пожалуйста, код в вопрос :) По-идеи, все символы в консоли должны быть моноширинными, т.е. иметь одну и ту же ширину на символ. Мб в IDEA кодировка не такая... Попробуй вывести приложение в консоли windows, например в cmd